# Adjust the height of UI-ICON-SEARCH for a specific Case

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I need to override the height of ui-icon-search for a particular case only (not for the whole appln scope) in the css.  I tried by putting this code in the css

```
.ui-icon-search{
        height:18px;
}
```

and i used in a span

```
<span id = '${spanLookup}' class='ui-search ui-state-default '><span class='live-search-icon  ui-icon-search'></span>`
```

but it will override for the whole appln. I need to override the height for this case only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override height only in a particular case, define a custom css class. For example:

```
.ui-icon-search-custom {
    height:18px;
}
```

Then in addition to `ui-icon-search` add this custom one to your span. Although I'm not sure what good this will do, because jQuery-UI icons are all 16x16 and in a sprite. Overriding height will just grab another icon's edges.